# I have a PHP multi dimensional associative array I want to convert into JSON that has an array and an object inside

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP array:

```
(
[username] => john
[attachments] => Array
    (
        [text] => hello
        [color] => green
    )

)
```

And I need to post it as JSON, so I know I can json_encode it and I get:

```
{"username":"john","attachments":{"text":"hello","color":"green"}}
```

But where I'm posting requires that 'attachments' comes through as a JSON object and *not* an array, like so:

```
{"username":"john","attachments":[{"text":"hello","color":"green"}]}
```

I could manually alter this string after I have encoded it and insert the '['  and ']' where needed, but is there another way?

Comment: there is a difference between an object and an array that has one element (that is an object) - if you want the latter, you need to nest that array one level deeper

Comment: do you want this:-  https://eval.in/680969      ?

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, and the demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$foo['attachments'] = [(object) $foo['attachments']];
```

Cast the array to an object, wrap in an array again, and then use json_encode on the result.

Comment: Brilliant. Wondered how to do that! Cheers